# Duvida sobre substituições em python metodo replace, como acessar melhor as listas?

Tags: python, python-3.x

3. fix_start

Dada uma string s, retorne uma string onde
todas as ocorrências do primeiro caracter de s
foram substituidas por '*', exceto a primeira.

Exemplo: 'babble' retorna 'ba**le'

Assuma que a string tem tamanho 1 ou maior.

Dica: s.replace(stra, strb) retorna uma versão da string s
onde todas as instancias de stra foram substituidas por strb.

```
def fix_start(s):
    # +++ SUA SOLUÇÃO +++
    if s[:2] == s[:1:1]:
        return s.replace(s[1:], '*',)
    


# --- Daqui para baixo são apenas códigos auxiliáries de teste. ---

def test(f, in_, expected):
    """
    Executa a função f com o parâmetro in_ e compara o resultado com expected.
    :return: Exibe uma mensagem indicando se a função f está correta ou não.
    """
    out = f(in_)

    if out == expected:
        sign = '✅'
        info = ''
    else:
        sign = '❌'
        info = f'e o correto é {expected!r}'

    print(f'{sign} {f.__name__}({in_!r}) retornou {out!r} {info}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Testes que verificam o resultado do seu código em alguns cenários.
    test(fix_start, 'babble', 'ba**le')
    test(fix_start, 'aardvark', 'a*rdv*rk')
    test(fix_start, 'google', 'goo*le')
    test(fix_start, 'donut', 'donut')
```

Comment: Escreveu tudo isso para perguntar se há maneira melhor de escrever isso `s.replace(s[1:], '*')`  ???

Comment: não, está retornando a string completa, ou seja ta retornando 'b*', e o correto era retornar 'ba**le

Comment: @AugustoVasques

Comment: `s[:1:1]` retorna o primeiro caractere da string (é o mesmo que `s[0]`) e `s[:2]` retorna os dois primeiros caracteres da string, então essas expressões nunca serão iguais (exceto se a string tiver menos que 2 caracteres). Na sua [outra pergunta](/q/523440/112052) eu já deixei um [link explicando como funcionam os *slices*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295), sugiro que leia até entender o que está fazendo (sem ironia, é um conselho sincero). No caso, o seu `replace` está pegando tudo do segundo caractere em diante (`s[1:]`) e trocando por um asterisco

Comment: Se entendi direito, basta fazer `s[0] + s[1:].replace(s[0], '*')` - `s[0]` é o primeiro caractere e `s[1:]` pega tudo do segundo em diante (e nesse trecho vc troca as ocorrências do primeiro caractere por asterisco)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, vou seguir o conselho!! pouca coisa que li, já abriu minha mente muito!!!

Comment: consegui fazer da seguinte forma, mas ainda acho que não ficou muito simplificado:
    a = s.replace(s[:1],'', 1)
    b = a.replace(s[:1], '*')
    return s[:1] + b

Answer (score 0):

```py
def fix_start(palavra: str) -> str:
    primeira_letra = palavra[0]
    restante_da_palavra = palavra[1:]

    nova_palavra = primeira_letra + restante_da_palavra.replace(primeira_letra, '*')

    return nova_palavra 

print(fix_start('babble'))
```

**Retorno:** ba**le

Espero que isso ajude.

Answer (score -1):

```
def fix_start(s):
    return f'{s[0]}{s[1:].replace(s[0], "*")}'
    
    # alternativas:
    return '{}{}'.format(s[0], s[1:].replace(s[0], '*'))
    return s[0] + s[1:].replace(s[0], '*')
```